# Using JQ to convert plain text block to JSON

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I have a plain text file in format like this:

```
foo: bar
color: blue
names: joe, john, mary, bob, sue
```

I need to output the contents of this file as a JSON format:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "color": "blue",
  "names": ["joe", "john", "mary", "bob", "sue"]
}
```

I have tried using: `jq -R -n '[inputs|split(":")|[{(.0):.[1] | add' testfile` (let's say the name of the file is testfile) but I can only get this result:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "color": "blue",
  "names": "joe, john, mary, bob, sue"
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get the desired output? I've tried piping `split(",")` after `[1]` but it makes every value pair into an array, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Always split the value. If resulting array has multiple elements, then assign it; otherwise assign the original string.

```
reduce (inputs / ": ") as [$k, $v] (.;
  .[$k] = ($v / ", " | if has(1) then . else $v end)
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mvuvF8BpiN)</sup>

Or, check whether the value contains a separator first and then split, if that makes more sense.

```
          ($v | if index(", ") then split(", ") else . end)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xQ9jb_B7n-)</sup>

Note that you need to invoke JQ with **-R** and **-n** on the command line for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

With `--raw-input`, you're looking for something like this:

```
  [., inputs]                                                              # A
| map(split(": ")                                                          # B
  | {(.[0]): (.[1] | split(", ") | if length > 1 then . else .[0] end )})  # C
| reduce .[] as $x ({}; . + $x)                                            # D
```

Where:

- A: Combines first and last lines into a single array e.g. `["foo: bar", …]`
- B: Split each line e.g. `[["foo", "bar"], …]`
- C: Convert each subset into an object where first element is the key and second element is the value. The value is split by `", "` but if there's only one element after the split take it out.
- D: Merge each object into one with `+` e.g. `{"foo": "bar"} + {"color": "blue"}` => `{"foo": "bar", "color": "blue", …}`